# Проблема с 403 Forbidden Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu, веб-программирование, сервер

Добрый день, активно изучаю Ubuntu 15.04, поднял на нем сервер apache-mysql-php5, страница http://localhost все работает, сделал все как в статье http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/web-server ,при переходе по адресу сайта avtomir-kohana.localhost выдает ошибку

```
"You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server at avtomir-kohana.localhost Port 80"
```

Вот конфиг

```
"<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName avtomir-kohana.localhost
    DocumentRoot /media/danis/Danis/Web-prog/avtomir-kohana/
    <Directory /media/danis/Danis/Web-prog/avtomir-kohana/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>"
```

В etc/hosts все прописано.
Права на папку пробывал менять безрезультатно. 
Возможно проблема из за того что файлы сайта находятся на монтируемом жестком внешнем диске. Перепробывал советы которые нашел в инете, упорно не идет.
Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

возможно, что пользователь `www-data`, от имени которого по умолчанию работает `apache`, не имеет доступа (хотя бы для чтения) к каталогу, где расположен docroot сайта.

от чьего имени работает программа `apache2` можно проверить с помощью такой, например, команды (приведён и примерный вывод команды, где видно, что «родительский» процесс запущен от имени `root`, а вот «потомки», выполняющие основную работу, запускаются от имени `www-data`):

```
$ ps f -o user,cmd -C apache2
USER     CMD
root     /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

проверить, имеет ли пользователь `www-data` доступ к каталогу `/media/danis/Danis/Web-prog/avtomir-kohana/` можно, например, так:

```
$ sudo -u www-data ls -l /media/danis/Danis/Web-prog/avtomir-kohana/
```

понятно, что для того, чтобы просмотреть содержимое этого каталога, пользователь `www-data` должен иметь возможность просмотра и всех «промежуточных» каталогов: `/media`, `/media/danis` и т.д.

upd. вариантов решения несколько. наиболее легко описываемый: добавьте для каждого из каталогов в пути право чтения и выполнения для всех. примерно так:

```
$ sudo chmod o+rx /media /media/danis /media/danis/Danis ...
```

можно одной командой, перечислив все каталоги по пути к нужному, а можно и по одной команде для каждого каталога.

Comment: проверил, невозможно получить доступ к папке, не подскажите как можно права дать пользователю www-data?

Comment: @Danis92 дополнил ответ.

Comment: все заработало :) спасибо

Answer (score 1):

a2ensite avtomir-kohana.localhost делали?
В папке /media/danis/Danis/Web-prog/avtomir-kohana/ что-нибудь есть вообще? Если там ничего нет, то просто листинг каталога запрещен.

Comment: да линку делал, там полноценный рабочий сайт