# Ubuntu админка pgAnmin 4 на Apache 2 сервере выдает 403 Forbidden

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, apache2, http-status-code-403, pgadmin4

Такой вопрос [уже был](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162776/403-forbbiten-error-on-pgadmin4), однако ответа я так и не нашел

Может кто знает?

По [данному примеру](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-configure-pgadmin4-server-mode-ru) пытаюсь развернуть админку постгрес на сервере Ubuntu

Версия: Ubuntu 16.04.6

**Полученные пакеты:**

- Apache/2.4.18
- psql (PostgreSQL) 12.3
- Python 3.5.2

Конфигурацию Apache составляю следующим образом:

```
echo '<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName '$ip'
    WSGIDaemonProcess pgadmin processes=1 threads=25 python-home='$VENV'
    WSGIScriptAlias /pgadmin4 '$VENV'/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.wsgi
    <Directory '$VENV'/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pgadmin4/>
        WSGIProcessGroup pgadmin
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>' >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/pgadmin4.conf
```

В Apache не шарю, поэтому еще вопрос, какой `ip` должен стоять в `ServerName` (внешний/внутренний)?

Ну и соответственно, как решить проблему `403 Forbidden`?

Прошу, камнями не кидайтесь, поскольку в этой сфере у меня крайне мало опыта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423922/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-403-forbidden-ubuntu-15-04?rq=1), ответ на него помог

Предоставил пользователю `www-data` последовательно доступ ко всем папкам в пути `$VENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pgadmin4`, **раскрывая также весь путь к `$VENV`** с помощью команды `chmod o+rx`

Правда ошибка поменялась теперь на `500`

Для ее устранения нужно было переустановить Python-модуль `Werkzeug==0.16.1` взамен `Werkzeug` версии `1.0.0`